# Handle search click will route to URL and same time dispatch function on redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```js
handleClick = () => {
    const {providerName,googleAddress,planOption} = this.state;
     let params = {}
    params.providerName = providerName;
    params.address = googleAddress;
    params.planOption = planOption;
    this.props.pcpSearch(params); //redux call disptach

    let pathName = customerId ? `/providers/customers/${customerId}/list/` : `/providers/list/`;
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: pathName
    });
  };
  
  <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Search</Button>
```

I have one small code which are used to handle the search click and at the same time it will route to specify URL ans also it will call the redux dispatch.

Here button will click so many times but I want to call route only on first click ? is there any way to do call route only once when button will click and after that not navigate to route on subsequent click.

Regards,

Comment: You should probably disable it after you click it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use state to handle whether or not it was clicked:

```
state = {
  clicked: false
};

handleClick = () => {
  const {providerName, googleAddress, planOption} = this.state;
  const params = { providerName, address: googleAddress, planOption };

  if (!this.state.clicked) {
    this.props.pcpSearch(params); //redux call disptach

    let pathName = customerId ? `/providers/customers/${customerId}/list/` : `/providers/list/`;
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: pathName
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({ clicked: true });
  }
};
```

Search

This should now only trigger once.